# How to find unpaired rows in TSQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, inner-join, except

Using 2008 R2.

My table should contain some rows that are paired - a Cancel transaction and an Add transaction, but we have some bad data where there's just a Cancel.

I am attempting to identify these and eliminate them. I tried the following code but SQL returned the error "All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists."

How can I identify these unmatched rows?

```
select *
from dbo.mytable t
where typename = 'Cancel'
except
Select *
from dbo.mytable t1 
inner join dbo.mytable t2
    on t1.id = t2.id
where t1.typename = 'Cancel'
and t2.typename = 'Add'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the `id` field in the select list:

```
SELECT id
FROM mytable
WHERE typename = 'Cancel'

EXCEPT

SELECT id
FROM mytable
WHERE typename = 'Add'
```

The above query selects the `id` values for which an unmatched 'Cancel' record exists.

Alternatively you can use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT t1.id
FROM mytable t1
LEFT JOIN mytable t2 ON t1.id = t2.id AND t2.typename = 'Add'
WHERE t1.typename = 'Cancel' AND t2.id IS NULL
```

Comment: Thank you - they both worked (now, why didn't I think of that?). The first query you suggested returned 3 distinct rows while the 2nd returned 10 rows that included duplicates (on that id).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select id
from dbo.mytable t
where typename = 'Cancel'
except
Select id
from dbo.mytable t1 
inner join dbo.mytable t2
    on t1.id = t2.id
where t1.typename = 'Cancel'
and t2.typename = 'Add'
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. This query took much longer than the ones @Giorgos Betsos suggested, returning 32 rows in 50 seconds (including some dupes on that id), although it ran much faster when I repeated the execution. I think I will go with his suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  *,
                SUM(CASE typename WHEN 'add' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY id) addcnt,
                SUM(CASE typename WHEN 'cancel' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY id) cancelcnt
        FROM    mytable
        ) q
WHERE   addcnt IS NULL
        AND cancelcnt > 0
```

This will select all transactions which have a cancel in them but no add, including other possible types.